# JSDOC documenting event listener (addEventListener)

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Concerning JSDOC:

After digging through the API, I am having trouble understanding the @event/@fires/@listens tags:

particularly, the @listens tag
https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/tags-listens
[image]

The tags are only discussed in a very particular context: user is creating custom events.

I thought I could use the @listens for a simple page load event.

```
window.addEventListener('load', currentWeatherConditions);
```

Even with the @listener tag added just like documentation, nothing about the event listener shows up in the generated HTML.

How can I get the @listener to be documented and show up in JSDOC's generated HTML? Nothing about events show up in index application controller module documenation where the event listener is:
[image]

I have started to use JSDOC which generates HTML pages people can view in the browser to quickly understand the application. So this would be nice if my listeners show in generated HTML.

Comment: Have you tried to relate the `@listens` tag to an `@fires` tag? Also, you wrote @listener in your post about two times, the correct tag is `@listens`, so maybe you just have the wrong tag. :p

Comment: Yes, I originally tried '@listens' but still can't get the page load event to be documented in generated JSDOC HTML pages. I'm not sure how to use the '@fires' tag here because nothing is 'firing' the page load event